# Postgres - Full Text Search to accept emojis

Tags: postgresql, parsing, full-text-search, emoji

I want to create a Full Text Search that accepts emojis on the query, or another type of index to search on text. For example, I have this text: `Playa  @CobolIquique h'` and PostgreSQL parse it weirdly on the emojis.

Debugging, Using `SELECT * FROM ts_debug('english','Playa  @CobolIquique h');` I have the following result:

[image: Results 1]

And I don't know why the token is considered an space symbol. If I debug the parser `SELECT * FROM ts_parse('default', 'Playa  @CobolIquique h');` I just get the same tokens and with the tokens types `ts_token_type('default')` there is not a emoji type (or something similar). So, How can I create a parser to split the string correctly with the spaces and doesn't consider emojis as blank spaces? or How can I create a text index that can use emojis on the queries?

Comment: I'm not used to full-text search, but have you tried with different dictionaries (like Snowball)? See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch-dictionaries.html May be you have to customize a dictionary (see examples in the previous link).

Comment: Yes, I have tried with different dictionaris (I have already build one with my needs) but the problem is the step before, that is the parser ):

Comment: Have you tried with `CREATE TEXT SEARCH PARSER` and `ALTER TEXT SEARCH PARSER`? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-createtsparser.html

Comment: I have read that page but I didn't get how I could personalize a parser (or tokens), I will play with it for a while

Comment: I believe parser tokenizes your string correctly, and it just can't convert it to lexeme (which does not surprise). I think your own solution (building a dictionary for your needs) is right solution?..

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm facing the same problem right now.

Comment: Sadly no... I never create a parser. On other site, I was hinted that I need to create the parser on C https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/156149/create-postgresql-fulltext-parser , but I didin't tried

Answer (score 1):

To create a new parser, which is different from default one, you should be a C programmer and you should write your own [PostgreSQL extension](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/extend-extensions.html). This extension should define the following functions:

```
start_function();
gettoken_function();
end_function();
lextypes_function();
headline_function(); // optional
```

As an example you can examine [pg_tsparser](https://github.com/postgrespro/pg_tsparser) module.